# Rendering Autodesk forge viewer offline on mobile freezes on chrome browser on android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have hosted my model offline file on a local server and I am connected to the same server everything is accessible to me via android phone.
I have create a sample project where the forge render offline model file which works smoothly on chrome browser of my laptop but on my Xamarin form webview and chrome browser the model render with lags as my model has too many details and nodes, I cannot even perform a simple zoom in zoom out functionality.
Now same thing when I am running on Ios(safari browser) this works smooth and without any issue.
I want to understand is they any such setting which effects chrome browser or native browser of android which loads model with lag
I have tried all the possible solutions available on google
1.I have implemented this in xamarin forms custom webview renderer and gave all the required resource that I can
here are the few settings

```
  var mWebView = new global::Android.Webkit.WebView(MainActivity.Main.ApplicationContext);
            WebSettings settings = mWebView.Settings;
            settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            settings.SupportZoom();
            settings.BuiltInZoomControls = false;
            settings.SetLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SingleColumn);
            settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.CacheElseNetwork;
            settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            mWebView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
            mWebView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = true;
            mWebView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);
            SetNativeControl(mWebView);
```

2.Added hardware acceleration in manifest also added heap flag to true in manifest
3.followed this too for autodesk memory limit {https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/memory-limit/}
4.I tested above solution with firefox and it works smoothly I am not sure what different they are doing to render this files

can any one help me what should I try to solve this issue
My device is medium end with 8gb Ram and 128gb internal space I am testing on 2 devices (samsung m40 and one plus 7t)

Answer (score 0):

Me to same Issue I am Unable To move Model in Android device. I am using the both online and offline Viewers.
I am Using Xamarin Forms Custom WebView Renderer as like Question

Autodesk team reply to us and Petr Broz solution plz

Comment: you can try running it on firefox browser it runs smoothly

Comment: Ronak Shethia Can We Talk on Phone once,When you're Free call me 9492563654

Comment: I have one Doubt ,When I am Running with Debug offline Viewer Using Custom WebView in Xamarin Android ,it working to View but When I am Installing App it not working ..Offline Downloaded data i was placed in Android Assets Folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this (running a web application inside a Xamarin WebView) is beyond our area of expertise but I would suggest the following:

- try running a vanilla three.js application inside the WebView, with a reasonably complex scene as well (for example, convert one of your Forge models into glTF using https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils, and load the glTF)
- if the three.js application has similar performance issues, it's most likely an issue on the Xamarin side, and something we won't be able to help with
- if the three.js application is working fine, please send us (`forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`) a basic Xamarin project with both Forge Viewer and with Three.js that can demonstrate the performance differences, and we would try and allocate some time for debugging it, and see if there's anything we can do to help

Comment: Thanks petr with above reference,also could u please help me what are the ways in which I can show my model on phones same like my web app

Comment: No worries. My understanding was that you have a Xamarin project, hosting Forge Viewer in a webview, and the viewer performance is bad. Can you try setting up a Xamarin project with a vanilla three.js app inside a webview as well, and see how well that one performs?

Comment: never worked with vanilla three js, let me develop some understanding on that and will put this on try